# Removing leading zeroes from a field in a SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a SQL query that reads from a SQLServer database to produce an extract file. One of the  requirements to remove the leading zeroes from a particular field, which is a simple `VARCHAR(10)` field. So, for example, if the field contains '00001A', the SELECT statement needs to return the data as '1A'.

Is there a way in SQL to easily remove the leading zeroes in this way? I know there is an `RTRIM` function, but this seems only to remove spaces.

Comment: As a upvote to David Walker's http://stackoverflow.com/a/11129399/1635441 response, please refer to Arvo's answer posted:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/662437/1635441

Answer (score 168, accepted):

```
select substring(ColumnName, patindex('%[^0]%',ColumnName), 10)
```

Comment: This will have problems when the string is entirely made up of "0", since it will never match a non-"0" character.

Comment: True. It will return all the unmodified string of zeros in this case. If this is a problem, the return value of patindex will have to be tested against zero.

Comment: @Zapnologica: No. You'd have to put it in an "update TableName set ColumnName = ..." statement.

Comment: Sure, if you use Update Statements.

Comment: Before using this solution, please try to look into Arvo's answer [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662383/better-techniques-for-trimming-leading-zeros-in-sql-server)

Comment: Here's a better link to the answer mentioned by OscarSosa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662383/better-techniques-for-trimming-leading-zeros-in-sql-server#answer-662437

Answer (score 34):

```
select replace(ltrim(replace(ColumnName,'0',' ')),' ','0')
```

Comment: I received "Replace function requires 3 arguments." I believe it should read 
select replace(ltrim(replace(ColumnName,'0',' ')),' ','0')

Comment: This will fail if the value has a space in it. Example: "0001 B" should become "1 B" but will become "10B" instead.

Comment: Like @Omaer mentioned, this is not safe if there are some spaces in string. Improved solution - first replace spaces with char that is unlikely to get in input, and after 0-ltrim, restore back these chars to spaces after. In the end looks quite complex :( Example:  select replace(replace(ltrim(replace(replace('000309933200,00 USD', ' ', '|'),'0',' ')),' ','0'), '|', ' ') --> 309933200,00 USD

Answer (score 10):

You can use this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE('000010A', '0', ' ')),' ', '0')
```

Comment: ey brother you nailed it..! a very single code that works!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same need and used this:

```
select 
    case 
        when left(column,1) = '0' 
        then right(column, (len(column)-1)) 
        else column 
      end
```

Comment: only works for a single zero, the poster asked for plural zeroes

Answer (score 5):

```
select substring(substring('B10000N0Z', patindex('%[0]%','B10000N0Z'), 20), 
    patindex('%[^0]%',substring('B10000N0Z', patindex('%[0]%','B10000N0Z'), 
    20)), 20)
```

returns `N0Z`, that is, will get rid of leading zeroes and anything that comes before them.

Comment: How is it a leading 0 if something comes before it?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the query to return a 0 instead of a string of zeroes or any other value for that matter you can turn this into a case statement like this:

```
select CASE
      WHEN ColumnName = substring(ColumnName, patindex('%[^0]%',ColumnName), 10) 
       THEN '0'
      ELSE substring(ColumnName, patindex('%[^0]%',ColumnName), 10) 
      END
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to remove the leading zeros from a string with a unknown size.

You may consider using the STUFF command.

Here is an example of how it would work.

```
SELECT ISNULL(STUFF(ColumnName
                   ,1
                   ,patindex('%[^0]%',ColumnName)-1
                   ,'')
             ,REPLACE(ColumnName,'0','')
             )
```

See in fiddler various scenarios it will cover

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=14c2dca84aa28f2a7a1fac59c9412d48

Answer (score 0):

You can try this - it takes special care to *only* remove leading zeroes if needed:

```
DECLARE @LeadingZeros    VARCHAR(10) ='-000987000'

SET @LeadingZeros =
      CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%-0', @LeadingZeros) = 1   THEN 
           @LeadingZeros
      ELSE 
           CAST(CAST(@LeadingZeros AS INT) AS VARCHAR(10)) 
      END   

SELECT @LeadingZeros
```

Or you can simply call

```
CAST(CAST(@LeadingZeros AS INT) AS VARCHAR(10))
```

Comment: The question needs to remove the leading zeros for 000000001A, both of your answers drops the A

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SQL scalar value function that removes leading zeros from string:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Vikas Patel
-- Create date: 01/31/2019
-- Description: Remove leading zeros from string
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.funRemoveLeadingZeros 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @Input varchar(max)
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result varchar(max)

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    SET @Result = @Input

    WHILE LEFT(@Result, 1) = '0'
    BEGIN
        SET @Result = SUBSTRING(@Result, 2, LEN(@Result) - 1)
    END

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result

END
GO
```

Comment: I'd try to avoid RBAR, personally: https://www.devonblog.com/continuous-delivery/unlock-true-potential-of-sql-server-by-avoiding-rbar-programming/

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server 2017 (14.x), `TRIM` supports removing characters other than spaces using `TRIM ( [ characters FROM ] string )`

Starting with SQL Server version 2022 (16.x), the `TRIM` function supports the additional `LEADING|TRAILING|BOTH` options
`TRIM ( [ LEADING | TRAILING | BOTH ] [characters FROM ] string )`

```
declare @string nvarchar(max)   =  '00001A';
select @string as [string]
     , trim(leading '0' from @string) as [trim (leading '0' from @string)]    --- Needs SQL Server 2022 (16.x) or later
     , trim(        '0' from @string) as [trim ('0' from @string)]            --- Needs SQL Server 2017 (14.x) or later
```

Keep in mind that **prior** to the 2022 version, `TRIM` will remove specified character(s) from **both** sides of the **string**, so `TRIM ('0' from '0000A1000')` will result in `A1`

[Source: learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver14)

Answer (score -1):

To remove the leading 0 from month following statement will definitely work.

```
SELECT replace(left(Convert(nvarchar,GETDATE(),101),2),'0','')+RIGHT(Convert(nvarchar,GETDATE(),101),8)
```

Just Replace `GETDATE()` with the date field of your Table.

Comment: How exactly does this answer the question?

Answer (score -1):

To remove leading 0, You can multiply number column with 1
Eg: **Select (ColumnName * 1)**

Comment: What does '1A' * 1 equal?

Comment: what does 10*1 will be ?

Comment: It was stated in the question that the column type is VARCHAR(10), therefore multiplying is not possible.

Answer (score -3):

```
select CASE
         WHEN TRY_CONVERT(bigint,Mtrl_Nbr) = 0
           THEN ''
           ELSE substring(Mtrl_Nbr, patindex('%[^0]%',Mtrl_Nbr), 18)
       END
```

Comment: You should give explanation with your answers, not just a single code snippet. Also, please format code as code (there's a button along the top of the text-entry box).

Answer (score -3):

you can try this
 `SELECT REPLACE(columnname,'0','') FROM table`

Comment: This will remove 0 irrespective of its position. Question is asking about only leading ones.

Answer (score -4):

I borrowed from ideas above.  This is neither fast nor elegant.  but it is accurate.

CASE

```
WHEN left(column, 3) = '000' THEN right(column, (len(column)-3))

WHEN left(column, 2) = '00' THEN right(a.column, (len(column)-2))

WHEN left(column, 1) = '0' THEN right(a.column, (len(column)-1))

ELSE
```

END

Comment: It's also not dynamic to allow for more than 3 zeroes.

Answer (score -5):

```
select ltrim('000045', '0') from dual;

LTRIM
-----
45
```

This should do.

Comment: There is no overload for sql server.

Comment: In PostgreSQL it is enought to write `select trim(leading '0' from '001A');`, but OP was asking for SQL Server.