# Attempting to import a csv into SQL Server that is lead by a random number of 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, flat-file

Basically, I want to skip the random number of zeroes. The solution, I think, would be to create a dummy column, in the format file, that ends on the first nonzero value. However, after scouring the net, I have no idea how to do that.

edit: To clarify each row is preceded by the random number of 0s.

e.g.

```
000004412900000009982101201021042010
000000935000000009902005199322071993
```

Comment: Can you explain - do you mean the file has a header with a bunch of zeroes, or each number field starts with zeroes, or each row starts with a random number of zeroes? Can you edit your question to include some sample data?

Comment: Sorry, but can you clarify some more?  How are the two example lines supposed to be interpreted?  Your title says CSV but I don't see any commas.

Comment: I guess it's technically just a flat file, that is my fault. Basically, assume I have one column that I want to insert, however each row of that column is led by a random number of zeroes. I need to get rid of those zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

First i'd import it as is to rows in a temporarily created column
I'd then create a user defined function or do this set based

That looped and removed the first char whist that char was "0"

```
TempCol = CASE WHEN LEFT(TempCol,1) = "0" THEN LTRIM(TempCol, LEN(TempCol) -1)
          ESLE TempCol
END

LOOP WHILE @LEN changes

@LEN = SUM(LEN(TempCol))
SELECT @LEN
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar on a MLS import. Here is essentially what I did.

```
BULK INSERT TmpTable FROM [CSVPATH] 
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',' , ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

Then fix the data you need to fix (the leading zeros)

There a few ways you can do this, but I will list two.

1. `UPDATE TmpTable Set TmpCol = CASE WHEN LEFT(TmpCol,1) = "0" THEN LTRIM(TmpCol, LEN(TmpCol) -1) ELSE TmpCol END`

   [2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662383/better-techniques-for-trimming-leading-zeros-in-sql-server) `UPDATE TmpTable Set TmpCol = SUBSTRING(TmpCol, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', TmpCol + '.'), LEN(TmpCol))`

Comment: Of course, a third option is to update using a Function as @Dmitriy has so elegantly suggested. However, removing the leading zeros inline will have better [performance](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/524983/user-defined-function-performance-is-unacceptable).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the first step of the .csv file import process is to get the file into a database. Then the second step is to clean up the data.

To remove zeros after import, you can create a function:

```
 create function [dbo].[RemoveLeadingZero](@strSrc as varchar(8000))
 returns varchar(8000)
 as
 begin
      declare  @strResult varchar(8000)
      set @strResult = ''
      begin
          set @strResult = Replace(Ltrim(Replace(@strSrc, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')
      end
      return @strResult
 end
select dbo.RemoveLeadingZero('000004412900000009982101201021042010')

update myTable
set columnA = dbo.RemoveLeadingZero(columnA)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
DECLARE @str varchar(100)='000004412900000009982101201021042010'
DECLARE @str1 varchar(100)='000000935000000009902005199322071993'

    SELECT @str,RIGHT(@str,LEN(@str)-(PATINDEX('%'+'[1-9]'+'%',@str)-1)),@str1,RIGHT(@str1,LEN(@str1)-(PATINDEX('%'+'[1-9]'+'%',@str1)-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER Function [dbo].[fn_CSVToTable] (@CSVList Varchar(5000))
Returns @Table Table (ColumnData Varchar(50))
As
Begin
If right(@CSVList, 1) <> ','
Select @CSVList = @CSVList + ','

Declare @Pos    Smallint,
@OldPos Smallint
Select  @Pos    = 1,
@OldPos = 1

While   @Pos < Len(@CSVList)
Begin
Select  @Pos = CharIndex(',', @CSVList, @OldPos)
Insert into @Table
Select  LTrim(RTrim(SubString(@CSVList, @OldPos, @Pos - @OldPos))) Col001
Select  @OldPos = @Pos + 1
End
Return
End
```

Comment: welcome to SO, it will be great if you can add some details to your answer explaining your approach/code, that will make it much more useful.