# strip leading zeroes in sql in string after space

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a contact number field which stores number as 
countrycode + ' ' + phonenumber..
Now i want to strip leading zeroes from phone number

I tried using

```
UPDATE [dbo].[User]
SET PhoneNumber = REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE([PhoneNumber], '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')
```

but this replaces the space in between with '0'

Any suggestions?

Comment: If a number is `000232656598`, it should be updated to `232656598` right?

Comment: This looks like it may already have an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662383/better-techniques-for-trimming-leading-zeros-in-sql-server

Comment: a number is like "91 009494949494" I need to remove '00' from the phone number "009494949494"

Comment: @AmeyKhadatkar:  You should have stated your requirement properly - see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting the value to `int` or `numeric`

Eg:

```
select '91 004563' as Input, CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING('91 004563',CHARINDEX(' ','91 004563')+1,100)) as Output
```

This gives the result

```
Input       Output
---------   ------
91 004563   4563
```

Comment: a number is like "91 009494949494" I need to remove '00' from the phone number "009494949494"..So this won't work

Comment: try to extract the part after space and convert to `BIGINT`. Then convert back to `VARCHAR` and concatenate. I have edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:   `SUBSTRING(PhoneNumber, PATINDEX('%[^0 ]%', PhoneNumber + ' '), LEN(PhoneNumber))`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
declare @PhoneNumber varchar(max) = '00000000000000000000001200000031'
while substring(@PhoneNumber,1,1)='0' 
begin
    set  @PhoneNumber = SUBSTRING(@PhoneNumber,2,LEN(@PhoneNumber))
end

select @PhoneNumber
```

Addressing your comment:

```
declare @PhoneNumber varchar(max) = '91 00000000000000000000001200000031'
declare @tempphn varchar(max) = substring(@PhoneNumber,4,len(@PhoneNumber)  )
while substring(@tempphn,1,1)='0' 
begin
    set  @tempphn = SUBSTRING(@tempphn,2,LEN(@tempphn))
end

select @tempphn
```

Comment: Well the solutions posted are already known - i wanted to post something different. User did not mention any performance issues.