# Right function + conversion

Tags: sql

I'm comparing columns from two tables. However, one of them contains two-value numbers (like `01`), while the other - one-value numbers (like `1`).

As a result, the following condition doesn't work:
`WHERE column_1 <> column_2 (results '01' and '1' are considered not equal).

I was told to add a zero to every number of the second column to the results and tried to use this:
`column_1 <> RIGHT(column_2('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), '1'), 2))`
but the error message I get from SQL management Studio is that "right function requires two arguments".

Does anyone have the idea what can be done?
Thanks!

Comment: how about simpler way, column_1 <> ('0' + column_2)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Better techniques for trimming leading zeros in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662383/better-techniques-for-trimming-leading-zeros-in-sql-server)

Comment: That worked! Didn't know it was possible, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should cast the string to integers ([CAST AND CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)) and compare the integer number:

```
where CAST(column_1 as INT) <> CAST(column_2 as INT)
```

Comment: +1, only that `column_1` appears to be already integer in the OP's question. Cast shouldn't be needed.

Comment: I thought of the covert, but had difficulties with the syntax. If that be possible, could you please show how such a statement should look?
Thanks!

Comment: ??? It's on the answer: `where CAST(column_1 as INT) <> CAST(column_2 as INT)`. Besides the "CAST AND CONVERT" part is a link to the MSDN docs which have a deep explanation and plenty of examples.

Answer (score 0):

As @JotaBe mentioned, you should compare integers, not stirngs.
But still, your code in second case isn't syntactically correct, it should be:

```
column_1 <> RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), column_2), 2)
```

But it won't work with negative numbers, for example.