# Trimming leading zeros in MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to trim leading zeros in a column using MS Access SQL.
I've found the topic
[Better techniques for trimming leading zeros in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662383/better-techniques-for-trimming-leading-zeros-in-sql-server)
but

```
SUBSTRING(str_col, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', str_col+'.'), LEN(str_col))
```

doesn't work in Access. How to "translate" it to Access SQL?

I changed the function `SUBSTRING` to `MID` and `PATINDEX` to `INSTR`, but it doesn't work

```
MID(str_col, INSTR(1, str_col+'.', '%[^0]%'), LEN(str_col))
```

The data type of my column is string and all rows looks like: "002345/200003", "0000025644/21113" and I need to extract "2345", "25644".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that the zeros really exist, they may if the field is text, in which case you can use:

```
Val(NameOfField)
```

Result

```
Field1  ValField1
ab      0
0000123 123
```

If the field is numeric, you probably have a format added to the table, which is a very bad idea.

Comment: Wow, it also solves my second problem, because I wanted to trim "002345/200003" to "2345" and the function trims it to "2345" :)

Comment: Be careful with Val `ab 123` = 0, but `123 ab` = 123

Comment: as mentioned by Fionnuala.. you have to be careful using val function. hence i asked the data type. In any case if your str_col has a non numeric char, val function will fail & return only numeric before the first non numeric value is found.

Comment: Thanks. I have all data in the same format, mostly numbers but some of them have a slash /.

Answer (score 0):

vba.Instr won't match by pattern. If your data column contains letters or any string and you still want to trim leading zeros, you could go for regular expressions.

Here a sample code:

```
Public Function FN_TRIM_LEADING_ZEROS(iValue As String) As String
    Const mExpr As String = "^[0]*" 'all leading 0s to match

    Dim mOBJ As Object
    Set mOBJ = VBA.CreateObject("vbscript.RegExp")

    mOBJ.Pattern = mExpr
    mOBJ.ignorecase = True
    FN_TRIM_LEADING_ZEROS = mOBJ.Replace(iValue, "")

End Function
```

just call the function by fn_trim_leading_zeros(Value) and it will return trimming leading 0s.

```
?FN_TRIM_LEADING_ZEROS("00000000subString.AnotherString")
subString.AnotherString
```

or try this recursive mode:

```
Public Function FN_VBA_TRIM_LEADING_ZEROS(iValue As String) As String
    If VBA.Left(iValue, 1) = "0" Then
        iValue = VBA.Right$(iValue, VBA.Len(iValue) - 1)
        FN_VBA_TRIM_LEADING_ZEROS = FN_VBA_TRIM_LEADING_ZEROS(iValue)
    Else
        FN_VBA_TRIM_LEADING_ZEROS = iValue
    End If
End Function
```

Hope this helps someone else

Comment: This is RBAR so could be pretty slow.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the records in the varchar column are numeric, then you can simply multiply the string by 1.

Be wary though. Sooner or later something non-numeric will sneak in and break things by causing an invalid cast. If possible, convert the column to an integer type and leave the formatting up to the client.

Comment: This is an SQL Sever answer on an MS Access question. Why?

Comment: @Fionnuala what makes you think this is a SQL Server answer? It's not. I've done this often in Access.

Comment: Apologies then, it was varchar that made me think so, and so many MS Access questions get SQL Server answers!

Comment: Oh. Yeah. I can't recall off the top of my head the equivalent data type. Whatever it is, I think of it as a varchar in my own mind.