# T-SQL Join on foreign key that has leading zero

Tags: t-sql, join, where-clause, leading-zero

I need to link various tables that each have a common key (a serial number in this case). In some tables the key has a leading zero e.g. '037443' and on others it doesn't e.g. '37443'. In both cases the serial refers to the same product. To confound things serial 'numbers' **are not always just numeric** e.g. may be "BDO1234", in these cases there is never a leading zero.

I'd prefer to use the WHERE statement (WHERE a.key = b.key) but could use joins if required. Is there any way to do this?

I'm still learning so please keep it simple if possible. Many thanks.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662383/better-techniques-for-trimming-leading-zeros-in-sql-server) is not an answer to your question, but should lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, that prompted me to update my post because it's not quite that simple, serials are sometime alpha numeric so I need to drop the zero only if it exists if that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the accepted answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662383/better-techniques-for-trimming-leading-zeros-in-sql-server), I've written a small tsql sample to show you what I meant by 'the right direction':

Create the test table:

```
CREATE TABLE tblTempTest
(
    keyCol varchar(20)
)
GO
```

Populate it:

```
INSERT INTO tblTempTest VALUES
('1234'), ('01234'), ('10234'), ('0k234'), ('k2304'), ('00034')
```

Select values:

```
SELECT  keyCol, 
        SUBSTRING(keyCol, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', keyCol + '.'), LEN(keyCol)) As trimmed
FROM tblTempTest
```

Results:

```
keyCol               trimmed
-------------------- --------------------
1234                 1234
01234                1234
10234                10234
0k234                k234
k2304                k2304
00034                34
```

Cleanup:

```
DROP TABLE tblTempTest
```

Note that the values are alpha-numeric, and only leading zeroes are trimmed.
One possible drawback is that if there is a `0` after a white space it will not be trimmed, but that's an easy fix - just add `ltrim`:

```
SUBSTRING(LTRIM(keyCol), PATINDEX('%[^0]%', LTRIM(keyCol + '.')), LEN(keyCol)) As trimmed
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION CompareSerialNumbers(@SerialA varchar(max), @SerialB varchar(max))
RETURNS bit

AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @ReturnValue AS bit
    IF (ISNUMERIC(@SerialA) = 1 AND ISNUMERIC(@SerialB) = 1)    
    SELECT @ReturnValue = 
        CASE
            WHEN CAST(@SerialA AS int) = CAST(@SerialB AS int) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ELSE
        SELECT @ReturnValue = 
        CASE
            WHEN @SerialA = @SerialB THEN 1
            ELSE 0
    END
    RETURN @ReturnValue
END;
GO
```

If both are numeric then it compares them as integers otherwise it compares them as strings.

Comment: Thanks, but they can be alpha numeric too. Could I test for an int somehow then use then use the CASE statement to convert if true?

Comment: Answer replaced by function to check for both types

Comment: Thank you, one for the tool kit :)