# SQL Server: How to keep track of CURRENT occurrence of A substring in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns, `PO_NUMBER` and `PO_COUNTER`. `PO_NUMBER` column has many PO numbers. For example, 601A-00001, 601A-00002, 601A-00003....601A-00101. I need the `PO_COUNTER` column to count the number of PO's in each project. The project numbers are the digits to the left of '-' and the count should start back at 1 when their is a different project number in the `PO_NUMBER`. The screenshot pasted below is how the final result set should look...

[image]

I have tried using SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX.....

```
select PO_number, RIGHT(PO_number, CHARINDEX('0', REVERSE(PO_Number))-1)
from Purchase_Order
order by PO_NUMBER
```

but when there is PO_NUMBER 602A-00105 and 601A-00101 like shown above, my code returns 5 and 1 because those are the digits after the last occurrence of 0.

I have also tried...

```
select PO_number, SUBSTRING(po_number, CHARINDEX('-', po_number) + 1, LEN(po_number) - CHARINDEX('-', po_number)) domain
from Purchase_Order
order by PO_NUMBER
```

but this returns everything after the '-' and I don't want that.

Comment: Use the second option and trim the zeroes as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/662437/3770885

Comment: Look for the hyphen and not zeroes. As is you can just strip off the last five characters.

Comment: Isn't it the case that you want everything BEFORE the '-'?   And if it is, why couldn't you modify your second script to get it?

Answer (score 1):

Try make the following change:

```
select PO_number, try_convert(int, RIGHT(PO_number, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(PO_Number))-1))
from Purchase_Order
order by PO_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

If the counting suffix is always in `00000` format, then you could extract just that and get rid of the leading zeroes by casting it as integer.

```
select PO_number, cast(right(PO_number,5) as int)
from Purchase_Order
order by PO_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following makes a few assumptions:

- You are using a version of SQL Server that supports the ranking functions
- Every value in PO_Number contains at least one hyphen, and one or more characters before the first hyphen
- This *counts* the project numbers, it does not extract them the PO number... or how did you want to treat gaps in the data?

> ```
> SELECT
>    PO_Number
>   ,row_number() over (partition by left(PO_Number, charindex('-', PO_Number) - 1)  order by PO_Number)  PO_Counter
>  from Purchase_Order
>  order by PO_Number, PO_Counter
> ```