# Analog TrimLeft C# function

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I remove leading zeros from a string such as '0097619896'?

Comment: `CONVERT` it to an `int`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better techniques for trimming leading zeros in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662383/better-techniques-for-trimming-leading-zeros-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numerical data types don't contain leading zeroes, so you can convert to a `int`/`bigint`/`decimal`/etc and it'll strip them off:

```
SELECT CONVERT(int,'0097619896'), CONVERT(decimal(10,0),'0097619896');
```

If the values aren't numerical values, you can use `PATINDEX` to find the first non-zero character and `STUFF` to remove them:

```
SELECT STUFF(V.YourString,1,PATINDEX('%[^0]%',V.YourString)-1,'')
FROM (VALUES('0097619896-abc'))V(YourString);
```