# How to replace starting two digit (00) with blank space in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where as codes are present in the form of 78,7244,d345 by default few records are found where the codes are start with 0072 .

I have to delete starting two number (00) from all codes wherever its present in column.

Comment: Sample data, expected results, *and* your attempts and details of why they didn't work will help us help you.

Comment: Better question is why you store a series of values (numbers?) in a CSV string. This would be trivial (or even non-existent) if the table were properly normalized.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @SMor    The reason why someone asks a question like this is because they've gotten data from an outside source they have no control over and they want to fix it.

Comment: @pinkysharma - Are you saying that your example of 78,7244,d345 is 3 codes stored as a CSV in a single column?  Are you also saying that any of those 3 codes could have a leading "00"?  And are you saying that you want to leave it as a CSV after deleting the offending leading "00" from any of the 3 codes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better techniques for trimming leading zeros in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662383/better-techniques-for-trimming-leading-zeros-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test for it like:

```sql
select 
    case 
        when code like '00%' 
        then right(code,len(code)-2) 
        else code end AS Code
from YourTable
```