# ltrim in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have this data in my tables
Table1: 
ProfileID: 0014, 0012, 001
Table2: PurchasedprofileID: 14, 12, 1

```
select * from Table1 join Table2
on Table1.profileID = Table2.PurchasedprofileID

Should return : 14, 12, 1
```

How do I use the LTRIM or REPLACE to trim the leading zeros

ProfileId, PurchasedprofileID is of datatype varchar

Thanks
Sun

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing leading zeroes from a field in a SQL statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92093/removing-leading-zeroes-from-a-field-in-a-sql-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For profileID use `CAST ( profileID AS Integer)`

Also CAST should be used in JOIN

```
select * from Table1 join Table2
on CAST(Table1.profileID AS Integer)= CAST(Table2.PurchasedprofileID AS Integer)
```

In case that non number exist's

```
SUBSTRING( -- get the substing
profileID
,PATINDEX ( '%[^0]%' , profileID ) -- find the first non zero char
,LEN(profileId)+1-PATINDEX ( '%[^0]%' , expression ) -- calculate the rest string length from the first non zero character
)
```

Comment: What if one of the `ProfileID` values is non-numeric (e.g., '0014A')?

Comment: Good point. My answer is based on @Sun's sample data, I assumed only number characters are contained in the string

Comment: Yes, that is essentially the code given in the question I identified as a possible duplicate of this question.

Comment: Yes the question is similar, but i think the code does not calculate the appropriate string length.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the result as a character type then I think it would be best to Cast the result as an Integer.

Comment: Deleted my post with same answer..  Yes.  The leading zeros should automatically fall off the numbers if converted to a numeric data type.