# How to trim leading single quote and leading zeros from sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to compare two columns in a sql table. The data in one column has a leading single quote and may have leading zeros and the other column may have leading zeros. I need to trim the leading zeros off one column and the leading quote and leading zeros on the other before I do the comparison. Is this Possible?

```
    F.RoutingNum
    123456
    234356
    014233
    233455


    T.RoutingNum
    '123456
    '234356
    '014233
    '0233455
```

I tried this but it does not trim to leading zeros off the T.RoutingNum column.

```
CASE 
    WHEN Replace(Ltrim(Replace(F.RoutingNum, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0') 
        <> SUBSTRING(Replace(Ltrim(Replace(T.RoutingNum, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0'), 2, 20) 
        THEN 'DO not match' 
    ELSE 'match'
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
case
    when cast(isnull(f.routingnum, 0) as bigint) 
        <> cast(isnull(replace(t.routingnum, '''', ''), 0) as bigint)
        then 'do not match'
    else
        'match'
end
```

Comment: I get this error, The conversion of the nvarchar value '3114970664' overflowed an int column. Is there a way around this? Thanks

Comment: @user973671 use `bigint` or `decimal`.  What's the largest value you will see??

Comment: cast(F.RoutingNum as decimal) works but cast(replace(T.RoutingNum, '''', '') as decimal) gives the error, Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric. I am guessing the single quote is not being removed before it is getting cast. Any suggestions? thanks

Comment: @user973671 see my edit.  Try using `bigint`.  Also, with `decimal`, specify the precision and scale.  I.e. `cast(replace(t.routingnum, '''', '') as decimal(20, 0)` or something to that effect.  Make sure your `replace` is using only single quotes.  The second parameter is 4 single quotes, and the third param is 2 single quotes.

Comment: There is also some null values in the T.RoutingNum column, maybe that is why it is giving me that error.

Comment: That did not seem to work. I will keep working on it Thanks for all you help.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good write-up on how to remove leading zeroes depending on your data type:
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/trim-leading-zeros.aspx

If your RoutingNum is actually numeric it's as easy as casting it to an `INT`

Here is a related question which probably also answers your problem:
[Removing leading zeroes from a field in a SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92093/removing-leading-zeroes-from-a-field-in-a-sql-statement)

**EDIT:** And, I just confirmed that these same results are easily determined using this method:
http://bit.ly/vQYVal

Comment: +1 - I was about to suggest trimming the quote and casting to `INT`