# Trim leading 0s from string in T-Sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing leading zeroes from a field in a SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92093/removing-leading-zeroes-from-a-field-in-a-sql-statement)

In a SQL Server 2008 database I have a string column which I need to select with the leading "0"s removed. E.g. `0023AFF` should be returned as `23AFF`.
Is this possible in T-Sql and how?

Comment: See this Stack Overflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92093/removing-leading-zeroes-from-a-field-in-a-sql-statement

Comment: @Aziz, thanks. I didn't find that on my search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`PatIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

```
declare @s varchar(20)='0023aff'

select substring(@s,PATINDEX('%[^0]%',@s),LEN(@s))
```