# T-SQL Remove Zero Padding as String Manipulation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, padding

If you are dealing with strings as nvarchar and varchar in SQL Server what is the correct way to drop leading zeros without casting to an INT type?

Say '000123' for example. I would like to convert this into '123'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92093/removing-leading-zeroes-from-a-field-in-a-sql-statement  This was converted to a comment because it was too short for an answer.

Comment: Then why not convert it to a numeric value since that's what it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Var VARCHAR(100) = '000000658410065446'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Var, PATINDEX('%[^0]%',@Var), 100)
```

OR

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Var, PATINDEX('%[^0]%',@Var), 
                   LEN(@Var)- PATINDEX('%[^0]%',@Var)+ 1)
```

Both will return the same Result as follows

**Result**

```
658410065446
```