# SQL Server : drop zeros from col1 and concat with col2 into new View

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I need to reconcile article1 (top) and article2 tables into a View displaying differences. But before that I need to drop all zeros from column 'type'. Create new ID column equals to filenumber + type so the resulting column should be use as index. All columns share same data type

Columns needed:

```
ID
C0016
C0029
C00311
```

[image]

Comment: Another approach not to drop but pad table2 types with leading zeros, check for `RIGHT` function in sql server.

Comment: Some sample data and expected result will be great

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize below script in SQL Server to get the format you want:

[Reference SO post on removing padding 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860651/t-sql-remove-zero-padding-as-string-manipulation)

```
SELECT CONCAT(filenumber,type) AS filenumber, type, cost
FROM
(
SELECT
filenumber,
SUBSTRING(type, PATINDEX('%[^0]%',type), 
                   LEN(type)- PATINDEX('%[^0]%',type)+ 1) AS type, cost
FROM 
(
 VALUES 
  ('C001','00006',40),
   ('C002','00009',80),
   ('C003','00011',120)
  ) as t(filenumber,type, cost)
 ) AS t
```

**Resultset**

```
+------------+------+------+
| filenumber | type | cost |
+------------+------+------+
| C0016      |    6 |   40 |
| C0029      |    9 |   80 |
| C00311     |   11 |  120 |
+------------+------+------+
```

Comment: Where/how do I enter the actual table name?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try_convert()` :

```
alter table table_name
    add id as concat(filenumber, try_convert(int, type)) persisted -- physical storage
```

If you want a view :

```
create view veiw_name 
as 
   select t.*, concat(filenumber, try_convert(int, type)) as id
   from table t;
```

`try_convert()` will return null whereas conversation fails.

Comment: the above does the conversion, creates the new column but with 6 spaces between the two values. i.e. line one ID value is 'C001      6'