# How to remove first N specific characters if they all are zeros

Tags: sql-server, string

I have this type of strings

```
01/CBA/1234567890
02/ABC/0000969755
06/DEF/0000000756
```

I want to remove the zeroes and get following output

```
01/CBA/1234567890
02/ABC/969755
06/DEF/756
```

How can i do that ? I though about combination of RIGHT, LEFT, CHARINDEX, SUBSTRING functions but have no idea how to combine them.

Any idea ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92093/removing-leading-zeroes-from-a-field-in-a-sql-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
SUBSTRING(myString, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', myString+'.'), LEN(myString))
```

Comment: Thank you this works :-)
declare @str as varchar(20) = '02/ABC/0000969755'
select LEFT(@str,7) + SUBSTRING(RIGHT(@str,10), PATINDEX('%[^0]%', RIGHT(@str,10)+'.'), LEN(RIGHT(@str,10)))

but why there is that dot ?:P

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

**Method 1**

```
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(100)= '02/ABC/0000969755'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@STR,0,LEN(@STR) - CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@STR)) + 2)+
 CAST(CAST(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@STR),0,CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(@STR))))AS INT)AS VARCHAR(20))
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51663/1) to view result

**Method 2**

```
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(100)= '02/ABC/0000969755'


;WITH CTE AS
(
    -- Convert to rows
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) RNO,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) 'STRING' 
    FROM  
    (        
         SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@STR, '/', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data      
    ) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)
,CTE2 AS
(
   -- Convert to int and then varchar
   SELECT RNO,CASE WHEN RNO = 3 THEN CAST(CAST(STRING AS INT)AS VARCHAR(40)) ELSE STRING END STRR
   FROM CTE
)
-- Convert back to / separated values
SELECT  SUBSTRING(
         (SELECT  '/ ' + STRR
          FROM CTE2             
          ORDER BY RNO
          FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000) STRING
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0728/1) for working solution

Comment: See the first method. Its not complicated. BTW I just gave a way of executing these in different methods. @Muflix

Answer (score 1):

Below Query will help you

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(500) = '06/DEF/0000000756'
SELECT 
  LEFT(@var, CHARINDEX('/',@var))  + 
  LEFT(REPLACE(@var, LEFT(@var, CHARINDEX('/',@var)),''), 
      CHARINDEX('/',REPLACE(@var, LEFT(@var, CHARINDEX('/',@var)) ,''))) 
                                   +
 CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(numeric(18,0),REPLACE(REPLACE(@var,LEFT(@var, 
        CHARINDEX('/',@var)),''),Left(REPLACE(@var,LEFT(@var,
        CHARINDEX('/',@var)) ,''), 
        CHARINDEX('/',REPLACE(@var,LEFT(@var,
        CHARINDEX('/',@var)),''))),'')))
```

Answer (score 1):

> use left and right string function

```
DECLARE @str varchar(20)='06/DEF/0000000756'
SELECT left(@str,7)+convert(varchar(20),convert(int,right(@str,10)))
```

[image]