# I need to remove all leading 0's in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, trim

So this is the query I want to use. I think it's easier to just look at it and see where I am in the wrong:

```
UPDATE * FROM 'catalog_product_entity_varchar' 
SET TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM 'value') 
WHERE 'attribute_id' = '176';
```

So in my table there are a lot of rows with attribute_id = 176, and the column "value" has a lot of leading 0's. I want to remove all of the leading 0's from value when the attribute_id is 176.

This is a bit beyond me, but it seems faster than trying to update any other way.

Comment: what is wrong with that query then ?

Comment: what db are you using

Comment: What database are you using? There seems to be a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92093/removing-leading-zeroes-from-a-field-in-a-sql-statement). Have you taken a look at it?

Comment: I'm using MariaDB (mysql). I tried running the above query and it keeps failing, saying I have an error in my format.

Comment: @PlacementEdge that is because you do... don't have FROM in an update statement typically.

Comment: Single quotes are for string literals. Use double quotes instead. (Or better don't use quotes at all, they are not needed with the names given.) I don't know if MariaDB handles this differently from the SQL standard, but as far as I see it, you are comparing two strings, 'attribute_id' and '176', here, so the WHERE clause will never be true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your SQL contains errors. First, remove `FROM`, it is not using with `UPDATE`. Second, write correct `SET` to update column, not just select.

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_varchar`
SET `value` = TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM `value`)
WHERE `attribute_id` = '176';
```

This must be working query. If this not works, add table structure and some data example, please.