# T-SQL remove leading zeroes in a string

Tags: string, replace, patindex

I have string like this:

00**876H873**            - I want 876H873

00**876 876500**         - I want 876 876500

0000**HUJ8  9IU877  8UJH** - I want HUJ8  9IU877  8UJH

I use:

```
SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(ColumnName, '0', ' ')),' ', '0')
```

This works in the first and second cases, i.e. if there is no space or exactly one space; however, if there are multiple spaces (such as the third example), I am not getting the right answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing leading zeroes from a field in a SQL statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92093/removing-leading-zeroes-from-a-field-in-a-sql-statement)

Comment: yeah; I took it from there only;  this does not work when I have multiple spaces; any suggestion on how to handle the 3 rd case, with 2 spaces

Comment: My input is this:  '00 11011 0'

When I use this, I get an space before the start of the result:    '_11011_0'

The underscore is a space in the result. I want to remove this space at the beginning; I am okay with the later space (between the last 0 in the result and the 1 that immediately precedes it)

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate flag raised in the comments will point you to a working answer, but you need to expand the length of `SUBSTRING()` to handle your data type.

For example, if you tried to copy the code exactly and run:

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(100)
SET @x = '0000HUJ8 9IU877 8UJH'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@x, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', @x), 10) -- note this uses '10'
```

You'll get the wrong result, `HUJ8 9IU87`.  This has nothing to do with the extra space: you simply are telling `SUBSTRING()` that you want ten characters, and it's giving you ten characters (which coincidentally goes up to the space).

If you expand the `SUBSTRING()` to a longer value, as in the following code, it will work as expected:

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(100)
SET @x = '0000HUJ8 9IU877 8UJH'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@x, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', @x), 100) -- note this now uses '100'
```

Set the length argument for `SUBSTRING()` to be whatever you need from your data type, and it will work correctly: it returns `HUJ8 9IU877 8UJH`.

---

EDIT:

if you want to remove leading spaces, in addition to leading zeroes, you'll need to change the formula to `LTRIM(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(@x), PATINDEX('%[^0]%', @x), 100))`: I put `LTRIM()` in there twice to handle leading spaces before removing zeroes, and after removing zeroes.

Comment: but this adds space at the start; for example:  SELECT '00 11011 0', SUBSTRING('00 11011 0', PATINDEX('%[^0]%', '00 11011 0'), 100)

Comment: I get a space at the beginning of the result in this case  '00 11011 0'

Comment: It doesn't add a space ... It does what we told it to, which is remove leading zeroes. If the leading zeroes happen to go up to a space, then that's what it gives you. If you need to remove leading spaces after the fact, wrap it in an LTRIM().

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did:  SELECT LTRIM(SUBSTRING('00 11011 0', PATINDEX('%[^0]%', '00 11011 0'), LEN('00 11011 0')))

Comment: Thanks, I have now solved this issue. Appreciate it; I added LTRIM

Comment: Excellent!  If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.