# Remove all starting 0 from a number

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have in my sql table different kinds of barcodes.

My Barcodes starting with 0 example

```
05212365489787
0000000290098
0000000000103
```

I want to remove all starting 0 from my barcodes.

Example result want to be:

```
5212365489787
290098
103
```

I found this Code: But i want to update them:

```
select SUBSTRING(str_col, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', str_col+'.'), LEN(str_col)) from table1
```

something like that

```
 update table1 set Barcode =(SELECT SUBSTRING(Barcode, PATINDEX('%[^0 ]%', Barcode + ' '), LEN(Barcode)) FROM table1 )
```

but i get error Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: make datatype as int then all 0 will be automatically ignored

Comment: Exactly just cast the data to `INT` or `BIGINT` depending on the data

Comment: The accepted answer in the marked duplicate specifically will not work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple modification to the accepted answer in the marked duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92093/removing-leading-zeroes-from-a-field-in-a-sql-statement):

```
select substring(barcode, patindex('%[^0]%', barcode),
                 len(barcode))
```

The accepted answer there has a length of 10, which is specifically incorrect for this question.

I will note that because barcodes are of finite length, you can also convert to a decimal

```
select cast(barcode as decimal(38, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `CAST/CONVERT` the data to `INT` or `BIGINT` depending on the data all the leading zero will be removed by doing this. Because leading zeros are meaning less in a numeric value so when you `convert` the data to `INT` or `BIGINT` leading zero's will be removed

```
Select cast(Barcodes as BIGINT) as result
From yourtable
```

To update :

```
Update Yourtable
   SET Barcodes = cast(Barcodes as BIGINT)
Where Left(Barcodes,1) = '0'
```