# How to use wildcard characters in this?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of this manner:

```
+---------+--------------------+ 
|ID       | Component          |
+---------+--------------------+
|00241147 | 000000001000245598 |  
|00241147 | 000000001000090069 | 
|00249207 | 000000002510256707 | 
|00249208 | 000000002510245146 | 
+---------+--------------------+
```

I want to select only those rows where Component is starting with '1'.

I'm using the following code:

```
select * from Table where Component like '%1%'
```

Comment: @UweKeim tried that, doesn't work

Comment: Do you want to avoid leading zero (0) ?

Comment: See [Removing leading zeroes from a field in a SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/92093/107625), then do `LIKE '1%'` on the trimmed value.

Comment: @GaurangDave yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast them as bigint and read 1 using `left()` function

```
select * from Table where left(cast(Component as bigint), 1) = 1
```

**Note** : This above assumes that Component column  has varchar datatype

**EDIT :** Thanks for making demo for clarification by **Uwe Keim**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1987d/4

Comment: [Here is a working SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1987d/4) with your above code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
WHERE SUBSTRING(str_col, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', str_col+'.'), LEN(str_col)) LIKE '1%';
```

Comment: [Here is a working SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1987d/7/0) based upon your above code.

Comment: its not loading but hope it helped you.