# Suppressing leading zeros from varchar field used in a string

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a `varchar` value: which takes the following value:

```
0000151010
```

from the database

I need this value to show as

```
151010 (without zeros)
```

```
//converting the columns returned to strings.
DBInvoiceModel invoiceRecord = new DBInvoiceModel
{
    //here's the value in the string
    TranNo = reader[1].ToString()
};
result.Add(invoiceRecord);
```

I need help suppressing the leading zeros

Comment: You could do `reader[1].ToString().TrimStart('0')`

Answer (score 0):

Just use Trimstart

```
TranNo = reader[1].ToString().TrimStart(new Char[] { '0' } );
//Console.WriteLine(TranNo);
```

---

```
//converting the columns returned to strings.
DBInvoiceModel invoiceRecord = new DBInvoiceModel
{
    //here's the value in the string, trimmed out
    TranNo = reader[1].ToString().TrimStart(new Char[] {'0'});
};
result.Add(invoiceRecord);
```

---

if you want to remove it in Sql Server [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/92363/6085193)

```
select substring(ColumnName, patindex('%[^0]%',ColumnName), 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use regex to get the value without leading zeros.

Code:

```
    Regex rx = new Regex(@"^0+(\d+)$");
    Console.WriteLine(rx.Replace("0000151010", @"$1") );
```

Result:

```
151010
```