# T-SQL removing leading fixed string with filling zeros

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to remove leading characters with variable zeros in my column. The string always starts with '049' + filling zeros + some number. I need to extract the number after leading zeros.

```
04912040 -> 12040
04901204 -> 1204
04900100 -> 100
04900012 -> 12
04900008 -> 8
```

I have found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92093/removing-leading-zeroes-from-a-field-in-a-sql-statement) and added replace for the leading '049' to be replaced with '000':

```
SUBSTRING(mycolumn, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', REPLACE(mycolumn, '049', '000')), LEN(mycolumn))
```

However, this won't work if my string looks like `04904901`, since instead of `4901` I will get `1`.

Comment: How, pray tell, does the title relate to the question? Is that what you searched for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the first 3 characters and convert it to an `int`:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(int,STUFF(YourColumn,1,3,''))
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8ddd1d2dfaf980f63e84aa6c45aca353)